# what cpu will work with hyper v

Tags: hardware, hyper-v

how do i verify if a cpu has the necessary requirements to run hyper v ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Hyper-V FAQ:

```
Q.  What are the system requirements for Hyper-V?

A.  In addition to the systems requirement for Windows Server 2008, 
    the two key requirements for the Hyper-V platform are the need 
    to ensure that the server is a 64-bit environment and supports 
    hardware-assisted virtualization (Intel VT or AMD-V) technology.
```

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/hyperv-faq.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use a tool called [SecurAble](http://www.grc.com/files/securable.exe) which will tell you if your CPU supports Virtualisation Technologies, which is what you need to run Hyper-V.  It will also tell you the number of bits supported by your CPU and if it supports DEP

Comment: +1 for SecurAble if you already have the CPU in question in a running machine.  Here is the web page explaining SecurAble:

http://www.grc.com/securable.htm

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU must support [Virtualization extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization).  An easy way to check this is to search for your CPU model number in Google and look for a NewEgg.com link (this will find old models, unlike NewEgg's search).  Check the "Virtualization Technology Support" field.

Be aware that this feature is typically disabled by default in the BIOS.

Comment: Extension names for Intel are VT-i and VT-d. For AMD it's AMD-V.

Answer (score 0):

A great site to see if your intel-cpu supports virtualisation is the [Intel Processorfinder](http://processorfinder.intel.com/), the cheaper cpu's often doesn't support VT.

Almost all recent AMD processors support AMD-V.