# Which CPUs support VT-x?

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit

I did some searches, but I was unable to find a list of which CPU models support VT-x and which do not. Where can I find such a list?

Comment: Related info (but from a post-purchase angle) http://serverfault.com/questions/14275/what-cpu-will-work-with-hyper-v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_microprocessors for Intel (search for 'VT') and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_microprocessors
 for AMD (search for 'AMD-V').

Answer (score 3):

This [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_VT#Hardware_support) has a reasonably good sample of both AMD (V) and Intel (VT-x) processors.

Answer (score 2):

Intel's [ARK site](http://ark.intel.com) is pretty awesome for finding out info on all Intel products (not just CPUs but motherboards, ethernet controllers, and chipsets).

ARK has a list of Intel CPUs that support VT-x here:
http://ark.intel.com/VTList.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For intels there's a really nice page:

- http://processorfinder.intel.com

Just go there and choose the "Intel Advanced Virtualization Technology" in the feature list. That is the second page after choosing the processor family.

Anyone knows a similiar site for AMD? I think it's a real lack of care that they don't have it easily available...

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the CPU and you're using Linux you can check it programmatically like this:

```
$ grep ^flags /proc/cpuinfo | egrep '(vmx|svm}'
```

If this matches you have the virtualization CPU extensions (vmx==Intel, svm==AMD).

Make sure to enable VT in the system BIOS.

Answer (score -1):

http://intel.com for VT-x & http://amd.com V-x