# KVM Virtualization on AMD64 running Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-9.04

I want to setup KVM virtualization on my laptop Dell Inspiron 1526 (AMD64 Turion, 2GB RAM)
running Ubuntu 9.04 desktop, kernel 2.6.28 and KVM-84 (the latest official versions supported by Ubuntu)

I can successfully create an image file using:
kvm-img create  -f qcow2 10GB

but when I'm trying to start a virtual machine:
kvm -hda PathToImageFile -cdrom PathToIsoImage -boot d -m 512
the host os restarts when the guest os starts loading.

I've checked the logs, there are no useful messages, only something like kvm module loaded, and enabling/disabling virtualization on CPUx

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: That sounds like a kernel bug.  Have fun with that.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is a bug in enabling virtualization on the processor. [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/14275/what-cpu-will-work-with-hyper-v) shows you how to verify your CPU has AMD-V support.

Otherwise, as the commenter said, it could be a kernel issue, or even Ubuntu issue.

Even if you don't think the messages are "useful" it may help to post the exact messages.

Answer (score 0):

KVM requires AMD-V support to work on AMD processors.  I've only seen reference to AMD-V being on Opteron processors.

Comment: AMD turion supports AMD-V.
I did some tests with Fedora 11 live usb, and KVM worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I would find that very unusual, I highly suggest to first go over; I know that Ubuntu by default goes the 'libvirt' way; however you should be able to install Ubuntu Jaunty and install the proper packages and get KVM up and running with minimal work.

Additionally it would be a great help to know what your 'guest' os is, for example; also check out [Launchpad Bugs](https://launchpad.net/bugs); and then lastly if that fails to work I would suggest updating to the latest version of [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) (kvm-87) as it more then likely help.

[Ubuntu KVM Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM)